# How to find the set of points at which a multivariable function is locally invertible?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Let,
$ f(x,y)=(x^3+3xy^2-15x-12y,x+y). $
And also let S $=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2: f$ is locally invertible at $(x,y)\}.$
Then which of the following is true,

1.$ S= \mathbf{R}^2 -\{(0,0)\} $

2.S in open in $ \mathbf{R}^2 $

3.S in dense in $ \mathbf{R}^2 $

4. $ \mathbf{R}^2 -S$ in countable.

By the inverse function theorem I see that
$ T=\{ (x,y) : x-y =-1~ ~or,~ ~ x-y =1\} \subset S$. Because $Df$  is invertible on the whole $ \mathbf{R}^2 $ except on the two lines $x-y=-1$ and $x-y=1$.

Now T satisfies option 2 and 3 and in the answer key the given correct options are 2 and 3. But How to find S? Since Inverse Function theorem is sufficient but not necessary, I can't use it find S. By nature of T can we conclude nature of S?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong,if we are applying chain rule then we are assuming that the local inverse in differentiable. Will it be always differentiable?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I took "invertible" to mean that the inverse is differentiable, but you just mean invertible as a set of maps, in which case, I don't see a good reason for the inverse to necessarily be differentiable. I believe $x+y=1$ should be $x-y=-1$ instead, no? Anyhow, 2. is true by definition of "locally invertible", 3. is true since $T$ is dense and $T\subseteq S$ and 1. is false, since $(0,0)\in T\subseteq S$. Not sure about 4. yet.

Comment: Yeah I get your point now. And you r right it was $x-y=-1$ . As you pointed, T is enough to answer this question.

Comment: Looks like the relation between $S$ and $T$ should be $\mathbf{R}^2 -T\subset S$ or, equivalently, $\mathbf{R}^2 -S\subset T$.